# How to access endpoint from express router in Cloud Functions Shell

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

(Note: I'm using javascript, not typescript in my Functions)

My Firebase Project has a single 'oauth' function, which has a series of endpoints created through express app/routers.

I don't understand how to run the functions at these endpoints from the Cloud Functions Shell to debug them locally.

Here is my index.js

```
const twitter = require("./oauth/twitter");
const app = express();
app.use("/signin/twitter", twitter.router);
exports.oauth = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My actual endpoints are in a twitter.js file (and others for other providers)

```
router.get("/authorize", (req, res) => {...});
router.get("/authorize_callback", (req, res) => {...});
router.get("/deauthorize", (req, res) => {...});
```

If I run 'firebase functions:shell' in my terminal, it only shows the 'oauth' function.

I would like to access a function such as 'oauth/signin/twitter/authorize' just like I do in the browser after deploying, but I have no idea how to!

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe this is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_https_functions) you are looking for. Essentially, you can invoke those *express-like* routes by calling the method (get, post, etc.) within the Cloud Functions like such: `functionName.get('/test')`

Comment: Perfect! Could you post this as a reply so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for. Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#invoke_https_functions) you are looking for. Essentially, you can invoke those *express-like* routes by calling the method (get, post, etc.) within the Cloud Function in the shell like such: `functionName.get('/test')`

Comment: JKleinne, thank you for your answer, I've been using it since!
One problem I have is how to specify query parameters, for example: test.get("/log_params?state=123&uuid=xxxx"). Do you know how to do this? The docs don't seem to detail it... I've tried anything I could think of.