# How to pass parameters when invoking HTTP function using Express App in Cloud Function Shell

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

This is similar to a previous [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790706/how-to-access-endpoint-from-express-router-in-cloud-functions-shell/58792120#58792120)

I'm testing Cloud Functions in a Firebase Node.js project using Express apps, and don't know how to add query parameters to my test.

Sample code:

```
const logUUID = (req, res) => {
    console.log("This function is executing!")
    res.send(req.params.uuid)
}

test_app.use("/log_uuid", logUUID)
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest(test_app)
```

I am calling it through this:

```
test.get("/logParams")
```

Which does indeed log

> This function is executing!

I don't know how to pass in a 'uuid' query parameter, even after reading [the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell) and the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) readme linked in the firebase docs.
I've tried everything I could come up with:

```
test.get("/logParams?uuid=1234")
test.get("/logParams",{uuid:1234})
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a 'qs' argument:

```
    test.get("/logParams", qs: {uuid:"1234"})
```

Or including the query string in the path itself

```
    test.get("/logParams?uuid=1234")
```

The problem in your code is that instead of `req.params.uuid` you should use `req.query.uuid`

See the difference between [req.params](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) and [req.query](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work (it just produces no output)

Comment: It's odd that it does not work as the firebase docs suggest that the shell works exactly like request.js, and from I what I just found here the solution should be what you said https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903926/6763963

Comment: Couldn't it be that it is working but I'm not reading the qs correctly in the function? I'll try again when I get home

Comment: Ok I'm starting to believe I need to use req.query instead of req.params